# Regarding Jquery Show/Hide

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to adjust this script, so that once you click on the image it brings down the other div and then once you click on the other it brings that information and not both etc.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.showHide = function (options) {
        //default vars for the plugin
        var defaults = {
            speed: 1000,
            easing: '',
            changeText: 0,
            showText: 'Show',
            hideText: 'Hide'
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        $(this).click(function () {
            $('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);
            // this var stores which button you've clicked
            var toggleClick = $(this);
            // this reads the rel attribute of the button to determine which div id to toggle
            var toggleDiv = $(this).attr('rel');
            // here we toggle show/hide the correct div at the right speed and using which easing effect
            $(toggleDiv).slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing, function () {
                // this only fires once the animation is completed
                if (options.changeText == 1) {
                    $(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Please advise. Thanks to http://papermashup.com/simple-jquery-showhide-div/

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?  What have you tried?

Comment: Just having a issue of how to get so it doesn't keep expanding the other divs. I just wanted to know how to do it, as I;m quite new to JQUERY and OOP in general.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the jQuery [toggle event handler](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), which lets you bind two functions to the element, and executes them on alternate clicks.  That way you never have to keep track of which click you're on, whether you're visible, etc.

Briefly, you'd replace your `click` handler with a `toggle` handler, which would then have two functions:

```
    $(this).toggle(function () {
        //what to do when your element is in its initial state
    }, function() {
        //what to do when your element is in its "clicked once" state
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm not being lazy but what would you suggest. I'm really nice to Jquery and just can't get my head around it.

Comment: I can't really make a recommendation because it isn't clear (to me) in your question what you're trying to do.  It just looks as though your function is more complicated than it needs to be and that using `toggle` instead of `click` would make it easier.

Comment: Ah I see JacobM. That makes even more sense. I will use it instead. Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: Added a little bit about how to use `toggle`.